# What can be said about how an automorphism acts on the roots of a polynomial in $\mathbb{A}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, automorphism-group

Consider a Galois extension $\mathbb{A}/\mathbb{Q}$ of algebraic numbers over the rationals and consider a polynomial $f$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with roots $\alpha_k$ in $\mathbb{A}$. Consider further that all $\alpha_k$ are **not** elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ (so that they are not fixed by the automorphisms in the Galois group).

Then consider the automorphisms $g$ in $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{A}/\mathbb{Q})$. Since $g$ is an automorphism, $g(\alpha_i)=\alpha_j$ by the properties of field homomorphisms.

Can anything more be said about which roots are the result of applying the automorphism $g$? For example, $g(\alpha_i)\neq \alpha_i$ for some $g$; can it be said when $g(g(\alpha_i))\neq \alpha_i$, $g(g(g(\alpha_i)))\neq \alpha_i$, and so on? In finite fields this is easier as we can compute the order as $|\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_{p^{q_1}}/\mathbb{F}_{p^{q_2}})|=q_1/q_2$, but how can we wrestle with this in the infinite case; with finite subgroups?

Comment: You mean $|\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_{p^{q_1}}/\mathbb{F}_{p^{q_2}}| = q_1/q_2$.

Comment: Yes my bad, edited.

Comment: If $f$ is irreducible, we at least know that $G$ acts transitively. It may still happen that some $g\in G$ (or some power of $g$) fixes some $\alpha_i$. Just look at the Galois correspondence between subgroups and intermediate fields

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Isn’t the Galois correspondence for a finite extension? $\mathbb{A}/\mathbb{Q}$ is an infinite extension.

Comment: I think your questions are too vague to have answers. "Can anything more be said" just isn't very specific. At the level of generality you've written, I'd say the answer is probably "no". Different automorphisms will act as permutations of the roots. They'll have some possibly complicated cycle structure. Some of their powers will hence fix some of the roots sometimes.